# Problem with a URL that ends with %20

Tags: asp.net, iis, redirect

I have a big problem.  There are devices in live that send the URL "/updates ".  It's a typo of the developer for those devices.  In the server logs, it looks like "/updates+".

I have a ManageURL rewriting module that handles all requests without extension. But this request causes an HttpException:

```
System.Web.HttpException:

System.Web.HttpException
   at System.Web.Util.FileUtil.CheckSuspiciousPhysicalPath(String physicalPath)
   at System.Web.HttpContext.ValidatePath()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ValidatePathExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

As I see in the logs, the URL rewriting module does not even get this URL, so I cannot fix it there.

Is there a way to handle those URLs with ASP.NET?

Comment: We'll need to see the code that generates the exception.

Comment: Are you using the IIS rewriting module or did you write your own module that does the rewriting?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Ok, this is an old thread, but I like to add a workable solution that works for all ASP.NET versions. Have a look at [this answer in a related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/429963/the-resource-cannot-be-found-error-when-there-is-a-dot-at-the-end-of-the-url/5272936#5272936). It basically comes down to registering to the event `PreSendRequestHeaders` in `global.asax.cs`.

Alternatively, when on ASP.NET 4.0 or higher, use `<httpRuntime relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true" />` in web.config.

Answer (score 1):

According to [some](http://dcortesi.com/2007/08/), this is in `System.Web.dll`:

```
internal static void CheckSuspiciousPhysicalPath(string physicalPath)
{
  if (((physicalPath != null) && (physicalPath.Length > 0))
    && (Path.GetFullPath(physicalPath) != physicalPath))
  {
    throw new HttpException(0x194, "");
  }
}
```

I guess you cannot change that, but can't one disable it in the IIS settings? Of course, that would also disable all other checks... :-(

Or write some ISAPI filter that runs before the above code? Writing your own module is said to be easy, according to [Handle URI hacking gracefully in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/594085/handle-uri-hacking-gracefully-in-asp-net).

Or, [create your own error page](http://brokenbokken.wordpress.com/2008/02/07/net-dojo-exception-handler/). In this page (like suggested in the URI hacking link above) search for specific text in `exception.TargetSite.Name`, such as `CheckSuspiciousPhysicalPath` and if found (or simply always) look at [`current.Request.RawUrl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest_properties.aspx) or something like that, clear the error and redirect to a repaired URL?

Comment: Thanks.
Sorry for not ansering so long.
As temporary fix we create a 404 page.
And find a way to change it on devices.

Anyway this error pushed me to find a ISAPI module that can handle those issues.

Comment: Welcome back ;-) Actually, I guess Cheeso's answer about using an ISAPI rewriting filter might be an easy workaround. This would then hopefully run *before* the above code is executed -- but I think Cheeso is the author of that filter, and I trust the author knows best. The single upvote for Cheeso's answer is mine, so: did you read that answer?

Comment: @AlfeG: Just to answer _"I guess you cannot change that"_ >> you actually can, by registering to `PreSendRequestHeaders`. See my newly added answer, or see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/429963/the-resource-cannot-be-found-error-when-there-is-a-dot-at-the-end-of-the-url/5272936#5272936

Comment: (Nice, @Abel. See also [How do comment @replies work?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) AlfeG was not notified of your comment, but will have been notified of your new answer, so that's no problem now.)

Comment: (Ah, I see. So in this case, only using @AlfeG will warn him, specifying multiple users won't. Tx for explaining)

Answer (score 1):

you could run a URL-rewriting ISAPI, like [IIRF](http://iirf.codeplex.com).

Comment: IIRF was not an ideal solution for our application. I'm waiting for release of 2.0 version.

Comment: IIRF 2.0 is out and available, though not final.  But there's nothing in the rewrite engine for IIRF v2.0 that you cannot get in IIRF v1.2.16.

Comment: Like I wrote in the comments of my own answer: I assume that IIRF runs prior to any built-in security in IIS? So, one could completely rewrite any URL (or: just strip an erroneous trailing space) before handling control to IIS, so before `CheckSuspiciousPhysicalPath` is invoked. Right? Seems like a good solution to me, but still the single upvote is mine. Am I missing the point here?

Comment: @Arjan, no I don't think you are missing the point.  You are correct that the ISAPI filter will run prior to System.Web.dll checking for a suspiscious path.  My comment about IIRF v2.0 was directed to AlfeG, who said he was waiting for v2.0.  I wanted to say, for rewrite purposes, there's no point in waiting.  IIRF v1.2 or v2.0 will both accomplish the goal.

Comment: Exactly what I thought. (I did understand you were replying to AlfeG, but I just fail to understand why AlfeG thinks IIRF is *not* an easy solution, even if only to remove one space... Not such a big problem after all?)

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to code why not just check for '+' at the end and remove it?