# WCF REST URIs ending in %20 fail with 404

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0, http-status-code-404, wcf-rest

A WCF REST web service provides a lookup in the format:

```
https://mysite/mycontract/search/{searchtext}
```

A search text of *hello*, or *hello%20world*, and the service performs correctly. However, when using text ending in whitespace as in *https://mysite/mycontract/search/hello%20* the service will fail with a 404. There is no custom routing.

What limitations in wcf routing causes this, and what workarounds (ideally besides changing the uri structure) are available?

Edit w/ additional implementation info:

*contract*

```
    [ServiceContract(SessionMode = SessionMode.NotAllowed)]
    public interface IPointOfSale
    {
        .......

        [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "search/{SKU}", Method = "GET")]
        System.Xml.Linq.XElement ProductLookup(string SKU);

    }
```

*method*

```
public XElement ProductLookup(string SKU)
{
   //product search here.
}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this (I correctly route with %20 at the end of URL) in my WCF REST service, can you provide an example?

Comment: @EkoostikMartin I think the key is that it's not in querystring, instead at the end of the route--can you see if that effects your results?

Comment: You are correct, I modified my URI to look like yours and I got a 404

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126735/problem-with-a-url-that-ends-with-20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been working with the same issue today, and found other posts telling that, in .NET 4, the solution lies in setting the following in web.config:

```
<httpRuntime relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true" />
```

This solved the problem for me!