# Double quotes into asp.net mvc url

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, exception, error-handling

how to handle double quotes in asp.net mvc url?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By URL encoding them (transforming them to `%22` which is the url encoded equivalent of `"`).

Comment: I'm getting "Illegal characters in path." for something like `/search/%22things%22/` -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087246/howto-allow-illegal-characters-in-path