# How to fix 'Illegal characters in path' on a basic MVC3 route?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, routes, illegal-characters

Given the following two routes:

```
        routes.MapRoute(name: "NationalRssResults", url: "{searchTerm}/rss", defaults: new { controller = "Results", action = "SearchWholeCountryRss" });
        routes.MapRoute(name: "CityRssResults", url: "{city}-{state}/{searchTerm}/rss", defaults: new { controller = "Results", action = "SearchCityStateRss" });
```

Navigating to `localhost:51860/fire-blanket/rss` returns data just fine, however trying `localhost:51860/SomeState-SomeCity/fire-blanket/rss` returns in an `Illegal characters in path` error.

These routes are at the top of my list so no others should interfere, right?

I have traced this all the way through the RSS content generation and always begins with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?><rss xmlns:a10="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" version="2.0"><channel><title>...
```

The view looks like this:

```
@model MyApp.Models4.ResultsPage

@Html.Raw(Model.rssResults)
```

I have already tried a few of the web.config suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087246/howto-allow-illegal-characters-in-path) - still no go.

I'm not sure why I'm getting this error.  Assistance appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I believe that you are getting the error because of the - between city and state.  Is that really necessary?  Why not do: "{city}/{state}/{searchTerm}/rss"?