# c# replace double quotes to empty string

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm replacing some characters to empty. But whatever I try, I can't replace the doube quotes.

What I try

```
deger1 = deger1.Replace("""", "");
deger1 = deger1.Replace("\"", "");
deger1 = deger1.Replace(@"""", "");
deger1 = Regex.Replace(deger1, "\"[^\"]*\"", string.Empty);
```

Some of these getting error. But none of these work.

I will use it for url rewrite. I'm getting "Illegal characters in path." error.

http://www.dinivideolar.com/video/400/muhammede-muhammede-%22aleyhissel%C3%A2m%22-muziksiz-ilahi

Comment: are you sure 
deger1 = deger1.Replace("\"", "");

isn't working? Can you provide an example of the string you are working on?

Comment: Use UrlEncode instead http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w%28v=vs.110%29.aspx Otherwise you will just run into another illegal characters error later

Comment: Could you show us your entry string !

Comment: Debug your code step by step to find why there are no quotes on your string at the first place, but some other encoding characters

Comment: you can either try with deger1.Replace("\"", ""); or corrected deger1.Replace(@""", "");

Comment: Do you need to change asp.net requestValidationMode etc.? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087246/howto-allow-illegal-characters-in-path

Comment: I tried this one deger1 = deger1.Replace(@""", ""); and I get newline in constant error.

Comment: try string deger1="hello i am \"\"coder\" ";                          deger1 = deger1.Replace("\"\"", "");

Comment: string=> hello i am ""coder"  output=>   hello i am coder"

Comment: @Ksv3n string is muhammede-muhammede-"aleyhisselâm"-muziksiz-ilahi I wrote url.

Comment: provide sample input and expected output.I think your question title and requirement are not matching.

Comment: @JayeshBhanderi my title and requirement totaly match. I want to remove quote but its not working.

Comment: okei.. Be calm. Can you please provide your expected output of above input?

Comment: sir my string is "muhammede-muhammede-"aleyhisselâm"-muziksiz-ilahi"

i just want to remove doube quotes and its not working.

Answer (score 2):

below code working fine.....

```
void Main()
{
 string deger1="\"muhammede-muhammede-\"aleyhisselâm\"-muziksiz-ilahi\"" ;

 Console.Write(deger1);


 deger1 = deger1.Replace("\"", "");

 Console.Write(deger1);
}
```

Result:

"muhammede-muhammede-"aleyhisselâm"-muziksiz-ilahi"

muhammede-muhammede-aleyhisselâm-muziksiz-ilahi

[image]

Comment: thank you but i stored the string without backslash.

like this
muhammede-muhammede-"aleyhisselâm"-muziksiz-ilahi

not like this
muhammede-muhammede-\"aleyhisselâm\"-muziksiz-ilahi

do you have any tricks to put backslash before double quotes?

Comment: can you place your code snippet here because i can't get it how you input that string and storing it.

Answer (score 0):

```
public string seoyap(String deger1)
{
    deger1 = deger1.ToLower();
    deger1 = deger1.Replace(@"""", "\"");
    deger1 = deger1.Replace("ı", "i");
    deger1 = deger1.Replace("ö", "o");
    deger1 = deger1.Replace("ç", "c");
    deger1 = deger1.Replace("ğ", "g");
    deger1 = deger1.Replace("ü", "u");
    deger1 = deger1.Replace("ş", "s");
    deger1 = deger1.Replace("  ", " ");
    deger1 = deger1.Replace(" ", "-");
    deger1 = deger1.Replace("---", "-");
    deger1 = deger1.Replace("(", "");
    deger1 = deger1.Replace(")", "");
    deger1 = deger1.Replace(".", "");
    deger1 = deger1.Replace("|", "");
    deger1 = deger1.Replace("'", "");
    deger1 = deger1.Replace(",", "");
    deger1 = deger1.Replace("[", "");
    deger1 = deger1.Replace("]", "");

    deger1 = deger1.Replace("\"", "");

    //deger1 = Regex.Replace(deger1, "\"[^\"]*\"", string.Empty);

    return deger1;
}
```

And in my repater I'm using this
      <%# seoyap(Convert.ToString(Eval("baslik"))) %>