# C# Putting a quotation mark within quotation marks?

Tags: c#

I'm using String.Replace to replace certain characters. How do I replace the " sign with a different sign of my choice?

```
artikelBezeichnung = artikelBezeichnung.Replace(""", "!");
```

That doesn't seem to work

Comment: Or `Replace(@"""", "!");`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9393879/double-quote-string-replace-in-c-sharp http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24652063/c-sharp-replace-double-quotes-to-empty-string http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905946/how-to-add-doublequotes-to-a-string-that-is-inside-a-variable http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9582781/c-sharp-two-double-quotes does this question shows any research effort? No.

Comment: even google answers it https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+replace+with+double+quotes+in+c%23&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary take a look at [this one then](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/948135/how-can-i-write-a-switch-statement-in-ruby) :)

Comment: It's useful to know how to escape things, but you don't really need to here. You want a char by char substitution (i.e. replace `'"'` with `'!'`).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Either:

```
artikelBezeichnung = artikelBezeichnung.Replace("\"", "!");
```

Or:

```
artikelBezeichnung = artikelBezeichnung.Replace(@"""", "!");
```

Comment: Did you meant `Replace(@""", "!");` ?

Comment: @Thomas no, on verbatim strings, quotations marks are inserted doubling them, so `@""""`

Comment: Thanks to everyone unfortunately google doesn't search for special symbols like the "

Comment: @"""" indeed, only 3x " makes a mess outta things ;) tyvmn

Answer (score 5):

Escaping isn't really necessary, since `String.Replace` [has an overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that accepts a `char`:

```
artikelBezeichnung = artikelBezeichnung.Replace('"', '!');
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a backslash.

```
artikelBezeichnung = artikelBezeichnung.Replace("\"", "!");
```

or adding the @ symbol

```
artikelBezeichnung = artikelBezeichnung.Replace(@"""", "!");
```

Answer (score 1):

The quote is an special char in C#. You need use it as an [string literal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(v=vs.71).aspx), You need to [scape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14480724/escape-double-quotes-in-string) [it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx):

Using slash:

```
artikelBezeichnung = artikelBezeichnung.Replace("\"", "!");
```

Or using @:

```
artikelBezeichnung = artikelBezeichnung.Replace(@"""", "!");
```

Comment: identical to @Jcl answer

Answer (score 1):

```
string stringContainingContent = "fsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsf\"sdfsdfsdffsd";
            string test = "\"";
            string test1 = stringContainingContent.Replace(test, "!");
```

You can replace using Skip Sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Using ASCII

```
artikelBezeichnung = artikelBezeichnung.Replace(Char.ConvertFromUtf32(34), "!");
```